# blending two images by Opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, blending

I want to align two images of different sizes using Opencv,
Indeed the function cvAddWeighted enables us to combine or blend two images of
identical sizes which is not my case !
so I need a help if somebody knows how to implement this function with
considering the different sizes for images

thanks
y.m

Comment: Are you interested in rescaling one image to stay with the same imensions of the other one?

Answer (score 5):

**First**, check [Adding Two Images with Different Size](https://web.archive.org/web/20121120002942/http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI)).

Another way to do it would be to set the region of interested on the bigger image using the width/height of the smaller (`cvSetImageROI()` will do that), and then perform the blend with `cvAddWeighted()`.

You can find some source code to do that [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121029114534/http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/%7EnoahKuntz/openCVTut2.html).

Comment: Both of those links seem to be dead...

Comment: @Seth Not surprised, this answer is from +10 years ago! Anyway, I updated the links from the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have two images that need to be aligned. You'll also have the amount one image needs to be displaced by.

You can create a new image that can contain both the images after being displaced. This means, it would be the height of the original image+vertical displacement and its width would be width of original*2-horizontal displacement.

Then you can set ROIs on this image and copy images.

Comment: +1 I am big fan of Aishack....I learnt so many thing from it...Can I get how to get rotation of head in 3d i jest need to know 3-angles...

Answer (score 0):

You write a Rect_from_Mat function which returns Rect(0, 0, img.rows, img.cols).

Then:

```
Rect roi = Rect_from_Mat(img1) & Rect_from_Mat(img2);

Mat img1_roi = img1(roi), img2_roi = img2(roi);
if(results_in_img1)
{
  addWeighted(img1_roi, alpha, img2_roi, beta, gamma, img1_roi);
  return img1;
}
```

Note that the 'addWeighted' line will (indirectly) overwrite img1's image data.