#  cvAddWeighted for different size of images

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use CvAddWeighted for different size of images .I know I can crop the size of larger image to match with the smaller image but I dont want to.Is there any other technique ,with which I can Use cvAddWeighted with different size of images ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [blending two images by Opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459960/blending-two-images-by-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the relationship between your different images. Assuming the smaller ones are a subset of the biggest one, you can copy a small one into an empty image of maximum size and then use cvAddWhatever on all the resulting big images. Of course it implies that you know before hand the maximum size of your images (or that you can store them somehow)

Comment: For copying small to large image ,I think I need to use cvCopy and that also needs images of similar sizes .

Answer (score 0):

You should set ROI on the images.

Comment: Can't use.Because I want to apply it over whole Image.Can't I increase the smaller image so the rest portion is filled with black part and the effective small image remain same?